# Email Address Auto Populate not working in Azure B2C Custom Policy and disable change email option

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Continuing from [Populate the email address text box in Azure AD B2C Orchestration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118940/populate-the-email-address-text-box-in-azure-ad-b2c-orchestration) something has gone wrong. The email box is not populating and I am missing something. Idea is to verify a login with Email OTP and then let then change/add Mobile number for MFA

UserJourney

```xml
            <UserJourney Id="TestEmailOTP">
        <OrchestrationSteps>   
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
                <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                </ClaimsProviderSelections>
            </OrchestrationStep>   
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>    
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyWithEmailOTP" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="NewPhoneFactor" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-EditAndVerify" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>   
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>   
            <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
        </OrchestrationSteps>
        <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

Technical Profile

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccount-EmailVerification" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
             <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />

          </OutputClaims>
           <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Rest of the "[SelfAsserted-LocalAccount-EmailVerification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54121225/10892195)" is the same as previous post and the claims etc.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccount-EmailVerification">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Email Address Verification</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.emailverification</Item>
    <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="verified.email" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The `CreateReadonlyEmailClaim` claims transformation is defined as:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

The `readonlyEmail` claim type is declared as:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
  <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

What am I missing here?

I also tried this but get a 500 error after login

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP">
    <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="verified.email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Also once email has been verified there is a change email option - we want that disabled or better - removed so that they can't do it after verification and moved to next step

Comment: I know it should be a inputclaim but if I put SelfAsserted-LocalAccount-EmailVerification as in IncludeTechnicalProfile to LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP - gives a 500 error. So not sure how to call that technical profile in there and then I guess we put readonlyEmail as inputprofile ??

Comment: Hi @Chris T. You must include both `<InputClaimsTransformations />` and `<InputClaims />` for the LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP technical profile. Can you also copy and paste the `readonlyEmail` claim type declaration in the above question?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I have updated the question with all the xml code. What do I exactly need to do in LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddressEmailOTP and what all needs to change in above code??

Comment: @ChrisPadgett tried various combinations but obviously there is a missing link here which I am not seeing...

Comment: Hi @Chris T. It might be caused by the `email` claim that's missing. The `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` TP returns an output claim of `signInNames.emailAddress`, not `email`, so the `CreateReadonlyEmailClaim` claims transformation should refer to an input claim of `signInNames.emailAddress`, not `email`.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett  Is it possible to auto-populate email when display control is used for email customization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @ChrisPadgett comment - The AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId TP returns an output claim of signInNames.emailAddress, not email, so the CreateReadonlyEmailClaim claims transformation should refer to an input claim of signInNames.emailAddress, not email.

Fixed by changing the transformation.