# How to auto populate email field on mfa page when display control is used in custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have to use custom email template so I added a display control in my custom policy, now I have following issues because of this.

1. When user logs in, mfa page with empty text box appears. I would like it to be auto populated.
   I followed the steps provided in [Populate the email address text box in Azure AD B2C Orchestration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118940/populate-the-email-address-text-box-in-azure-ad-b2c-orchestration)
   but seems like it doesn't work with dispaly control.
2. How to access/update "extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" field using ms graph api. I found one sample for this but it uses some id for "extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" which I could not find on azure portal. where I can get this id?
   "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions/{{ExtensionId}}"

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use InputClaims elements to prepopulate the value of claims to collect from the user on the page. Any InputClaimsTransformations can be defined in the self-asserted technical profile which references this display control.
   Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls)
2. In the Graph API you will get the extentions attribute value as: `extension_[GUID]_[ClaimName]`, To find GUID you can check in the `azure portal open ad app registrations -> b2c-extensions-app -> properties -> app id.`